# Using CALayer for UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, calayer, cell

I'm using CALayer to make good look to my uitableviewcells. I'm trying to do this in this way:

```
CALayer *btnLayer = [cell layer];
[btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[btnLayer setCornerRadius:10.0f];

[btnLayer setBorderWidth:5.0f];
[btnLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];

CAGradientLayer *shineLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
shineLayer.frame = btnLayer.bounds;
shineLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.4f].CGColor,
                     (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.2f].CGColor,
                     (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.75f alpha:0.2f].CGColor,
                     (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.4f alpha:0.2f].CGColor,
                     (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.3f alpha:0.4f].CGColor,
                     nil];
shineLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8f],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f],
                        nil];
[btnLayer addSublayer:shineLayer];
```

I'm doing it in cellForRowAtIndexPath method of my tableViewController. All works perfect, cells shine good but when i'm dragging cells top-down few times, top and bottom cells redraws again. After that cells become more lighter.

I use dynamic cells and load data from array. Give me an advise, how to do it correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I'm doing it in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

But since it's called multiple times (each time a cell loads **or re-loads**), you're adding more and more shine layers to your cell. One way to avoid this is to check if it's the first time a cell is used - in this case you have to create it **and add the shine**. So you can wrap the whole code that you have into the same `if` branch that checks for a dequeueable cell:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellID"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStylePlain reuseIdentifier:@"CellID"] autorelease];

    // ADD THE SHINE CODE HERE
}

// and **not** here!

return cell;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work in this way. Shiny effect did not appear.

Comment: How do you create your cells?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a generic UITableViewCell, you could create a custom cell subclass and add the effect in the drawRect: method.  I can't see anything in your code that suggests the shine effect needs ot react to the cell's data, so you may as well create the effect as the cell object is instantiated.  That should be marginally more efficient than doing so in cellForRowAtIndexPath: